# WebSocket - Close Frame

Tags: tcp, websocket, handshake

The websocket RFC states the following:

> If an endpoint receives a Close frame and did not previously send a Close frame, the endpoint MUST send a Close frame in response.

Later it also mentions:

> The server MUST close the underlying TCP connection immediately;

It makes sense when the server initiate the close handshake since on retrieval of the close frame response from the client, the server can do a TCP close.

What should happen when the close handshake starts from the client? Should the client resent some type of message to instruct the server endpoint to do a TCP close? or should the server do a tcp close on retrieval of a close frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the client resent some type of message to instruct the server endpoint to do a tcp close?

(a) That's exactly what the CLOSE FRAME message is for, and (b) no, the server must close the TCP connection immediately, as per the text you quoted.

> or should the server do a tcp close on retrieval of a close frame?

That's exactly what it says. After sending a CLOSE FRAME to the client of course.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the RFC says:

```
If an endpoint receives a Close frame and did not previously send a Close frame, the endpoint MUST send a Close frame in response.
```

This applies to both the server and the client. So, when the Close originates from the Client, the  following would happen:

1. Client sends `Close` frame
2. Server receives `Close` frame and echoes it back to the client, since it did not send one itself
3. Server closes its TCP connection (it must do this immediately after sending the `Close` frame)
4. Client closes its TCP connection. It can either do this straight after receiving the echoed `Close` from the server, or it can wait until the server has closed it at its end (it would know about this due to the connection state changing)

Comment: Is there a wat to indentify what kind of close frame it is. As per RFC 6455 "The Close frame MAY contain a body (the "Application data" portion of
   the frame) that indicates a reason for closing," I am trying to to figure this out for some time.